# Analysing JVM performance issue

Tags: java, performance, memory-leaks, garbage-collection, jvm

My application stops suddenly and i suspect it might be because of GC config needs some optimization.Can any one please advise on GC config optimization based on below data .Or anyone can highlight is any thing wrong in config

Below is my JVM configuration

```
-Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager
-Djdk.tls.ephemeralDHKeySize=2048
-Djava.protocol.handler.pkgs=org.apache.catalina.webresources
-Dorg.apache.catalina.security.SecurityListener.UMASK=0027
-Xmx21g
-XX:+UseG1GC
-XX:G1HeapRegionSize=24m
-XX:MaxHeapFreeRatio=15
-XX:MinHeapFreeRatio=5
-XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=4g
-XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError
-verbose:gc
-XX:+PrintGCTimeStamps
-XX:+PrintGCDateStamps
```

GC Configuration of JVM

[image]

Running JVM snapshot,

[image]

and below are GC logs that i can see in catalina.out.

```
2021-03-09T14:17:38.146+0000: 414469.095: [GC pause (G1 Evacuation Pause) (young) 17G->4391M(21G), 0.4270906 secs]
2021-03-09T14:17:47.284+0000: 414478.233: [GC pause (G1 Evacuation Pause) (young) 5191M->4216M(21G), 0.0419201 secs]
2021-03-09T14:18:13.735+0000: 414504.685: [GC pause (G1 Evacuation Pause) (young) 8488M->4280M(21G), 0.2362999 secs]
2021-03-09T14:18:17.606+0000: 414508.556: [GC pause (G1 Evacuation Pause) (young) 5192M->4216M(21G), 0.0566793 secs]
2021-03-09T14:19:06.833+0000: 414557.782: [GC pause (G1 Evacuation Pause) (young) 16G->4468M(21G), 0.5860262 secs]
2021-03-09T14:19:09.187+0000: 414560.137: [GC pause (G1 Evacuation Pause) (young) 5188M->4240M(21G), 0.0593960 secs]
2021-03-09T14:19:12.975+0000: 414563.924: [GC pause (G1 Evacuation Pause) (young) 5232M->4248M(21G), 0.0568061 secs]
2021-03-09T14:19:17.050+0000: 414567.999: [GC pause (G1 Evacuation Pause) (young) 5224M->4236M(21G), 0.0536786 secs]
2021-03-09T14:20:00.026+0000: 414610.976: [GC pause (G1 Evacuation Pause) (young) 16G->4341M(21G), 0.2910220 secs]
2021-03-09T14:20:03.929+0000: 414614.879: [GC pause (G1 Evacuation Pause) (young) 5253M->4248M(21G), 0.0200452 secs]
2021-03-09T14:21:15.569+0000: 414686.518: [GC pause (G1 Evacuation Pause) (young) 16G->4384M(21G), 0.2412292 secs]
2021-03-09T14:21:21.669+0000: 414692.619: [GC pause (G1 Evacuation Pause) (young) 5248M->4315M(21G), 0.0272150 secs]
2021-03-09T14:21:29.186+0000: 414700.136: [GC pause (G1 Evacuation Pause) (young) 5275M->4327M(21G), 0.0342030 secs]
2021-03-09T14:21:36.497+0000: 414707.447: [GC pause (G1 Evacuation Pause) (young) 5446M->4369M(21G), 0.0316144 secs]
2021-03-09T14:21:47.786+0000: 414718.735: [GC pause (G1 Evacuation Pause) (young) 7545M->4505M(21G), 0.0613017 secs]
2021-03-09T14:22:01.761+0000: 414732.710: [GC pause (G1 Evacuation Pause) (young) 8137M->4492M(21G), 0.1868154 secs]
2021-03-09T14:22:32.992+0000: 414763.941: [GC pause (G1 Evacuation Pause) (young) 6868M->4436M(21G), 0.0370628 secs]
2021-03-09T14:24:36.637+0000: 414887.586: [GC pause (G1 Evacuation Pause) (young) 11G->4468M(21G), 0.1404537 secs]
2021-03-09T14:25:14.738+0000: 414925.687: [GC pause (G1 Evacuation Pause) (young) 14G->4580M(21G), 0.2439932 secs]
2021-03-09T14:25:17.695+0000: 414928.645: [GC pause (G1 Evacuation Pause) (young) 5364M->4453M(21G), 0.0548354 secs]
2021-03-09T14:34:47.921+0000: 415498.870: [GC pause (G1 Evacuation Pause) (young) 12G->4549M(21G), 0.3198289 secs]
2021-03-09T14:34:49.145+0000: 415500.094: [GC pause (G1 Evacuation Pause) (young) 5429M->4437M(21G), 0.0055575 secs]
2021-03-09T14:54:47.263+0000: 416698.212: [GC pause (G1 Evacuation Pause) (young) 14G->4459M(21G), 0.1181888 secs]
```

Comment: To me it looks like your max heap size is too large (after GC only 5GB to 6GB are in use). Try running with `-Xmx8G`

Comment: What do you mean by "stops suddenly"?  Is the JVM exiting or being killed?

Comment: In some periods you are generating insane amounts of garbage. For the 30 second period from 14:17:47 to 14:18:17 there was nothing to speak of, then suddenly you generate 15GB in the following 50 second period. It would also be worth investigating whether there is any optimisation you can make within your application (e.g. object pools) rather than assuming that simply tuning the GC will be enough

Comment: @Michael is right on - there's not many apps that are going to use (and throw away) 12+GB in 2minutes.  If you can work out what they are, and potentially cache, then you will not need as much RAM, save on CPU, and potentially see other benefits ... For instances if you have lots of `new StringBuffer().append("A").........toString()` then having a `ThreadLocal` variable which you get() - and automatically reset - can save on memory allocations...

Comment: So your GC, cleared `10GB` ( for example from your last log entry ) in 1/10 of a second and you are not happy with that? In general, these numbers look very, very good for the amount of garbage your application generates.

Comment: @StephenC  as everyone suggested and that application jvm is fine ,and in logs i see that application is running fine , but after heavy load ui end stop getting response from backend tomcat server which is this JVM and it looks like that jvm is down . i was suspecting that is there any thing in jvm worth noticing which can cause UI application to stop  responding . also tomcat had to restart to bring back UI front end to normal where it again start receiving response from backend .Is there other parameter which i can look in to of tomcat server or JVM which can cause connection/http issue .

Comment: OK.  So you are probably "just" experiencing GC pauses.  (Your question should say that rather than "suddenly stopped", because "stopped" implies to many people that the JVM has exited, crashed, panicked or was killed by the OOM killer.)

Comment: To answer your question: not that I am aware of.  I suspect that the problem is that something in your front-end UI is *intolerant* of requests to your backend taking a long time ... or failing.  There's no quick fix for that.  You either get to the bottom of what is triggering those huge object allocation spikes ... or you analyze the back end <-> front end interactions to figure out what is jamming up.  (And I concur that GC tuning is unlikely to help.)

Comment: A slight variation on what Michael said: It is also possible that a request or requests are generating huge data structure over a space of 30 seconds to a minute, and that it suddenly all *becomes* garbage ... when its root becomes unreachable.  (If garbage was being generated continuously, it is likely that the memory usage wouldn't spike like that.)

Comment: @StephenC i agree , actually backend is receiving parallel requests as SOAP as well which  consumes lot of memory and creating this spike , but when this happens frontend ui which is made of flex unable to get response from backend and  requires server restart.

Comment: Maybe the real problem is the size of the requests, or that your backend is trying to process too many requests in parallel.  Or both.  Or maybe you need multiple backend services (with much smaller heaps) and load balancer between the front and back ends.

Comment: Thanks @StephenC . from the stats i can see CPU has never gone beyond 30% ,and it has extra capacity available , if you can advise on how to increase capacity of JVM to process more parallel requests . AFAIK tomcat can process multiple parallel request from frontend ,is there any other parameter at host or network side which can be increased ,so tomcat  and host/ network is the only area which can be issue . what is your opinion

Comment: I'm suggesting that you actually need to process >>fewer<< requests in parallel, not more.  Because it appears that multiple parallel requests is causing the memory spike.

Comment: And to somewhat contradict what I said earlier, perhaps you should tune the GC by 1) reducing the max heap size and 2) setting a pause time goal.  Then let the G1GC adaptive tuning work out the rest for itself.  As recommended here: https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/g1gc.html

Comment: thanks @StephenC i have started working on tuning the GC of JVM  , although can not comprise on parallel requests as application process can be triggered by many users simultaneously ,although issues started appearing when there is more than 4 or 5 parallel activity is going on , and strangely JVM graphs and CPU dont looks like overloaded .

Comment: I don't think that is necessarily strange.  If you are moving lots of data between the front and backend, or the backend and a database, then the bottleneck may not (normally) be the backend CPU.  (And we haven't looked at virtual memory / swapping / thrashing ...)  This is why it is important to understand the entire problem before trying to cure it with GC tuning.